# Can't find variable : initialState. I'm trying to map an array and display components for each array item in REACT NATIVE

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is a question concerning react native. I'm trying to render child components using map method. The App crashes when the page is loaded and im getting this error.

This is the parent component

```
<ScrollView>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        flexWrap: 'wrap',
                        justifyContent: 'space-around'
                    }}>
                    {items.length !== 0 ? (
                        <View>
                            {items.map(item => (
                                <SingleCard
                                    item={item}
                                    navigation={navigation}
                                    key={Math.random()}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </View>
                    ) : (
                        <Text style={{ paddingTop: 100, fontSize: 25, color: 'black' }}>
                            Please add a machine first
                        </Text>
                    )}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
```

This is the Child component (SingleCard) im trying to render

```
const SingleCard = ({ navigation, item }) => {
const macname = item.machinename;

const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
const [tokenin, settokenin] = useState('');
const [tokenout, settokenout] = useState('');
const [date, setdate] = useState(initialState);

useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, []);

const getData = async () => {
    try {
        setloading(true);
        db1.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                'SELECT * FROM data WHERE machinename = ? ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1',
                [macname],
                (_, results) => {
                    if (results.rows.length == 0) {
                        setloading(true);
                    } else {
                        console.log(results);
                        settokenin(results.rows.item(0).tokenin);
                        settokenout(results.rows.item(0).tokenout);
                        setdate(results.rows.item(0).date);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

const onPress = (id, machinename) => {
    console.log(id);
    navigation.navigate('Update', { id, machinename });
};

const deletealert = (id, machinename) => {
    Alert.alert(
        'Are you sure?',
        'Deleting the machine will also delete all the data updated by you for this machine ',
        [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                onPress: () => console.log('cancel'),
                style: 'cancel'
            },
            {
                text: 'Iam sure',
                style: 'default',
                onPress: async () => {
                    // await setbool(true);
                    // console.log(`into timeout ${bool}`);
                    deletemachine(id, machinename);
                    // setbool(false);
                    setrefresh(!refresh);
                }
            }
        ]
    );
};

const deletemachine = (id, machinename) => {
    // console.log(`into deletemachine ${bool}`);
    // if (bool) {
    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM machines where _id=?', [id], (tx, result) => {
            console.log('Deleted machine...');
        });
        // setrefresh(!refresh);
    });

    db1.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
            'DELETE FROM data where machinename=?',
            [machinename],
            (tx, result) => {
                console.log('Deleted machine data...');
            }
        );
    });
    // }
};
return (
    <View
        style={{
            // margin: 10,
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            flexWrap: 'wrap'
        }}>
        {/* <View>
                                    <Text>Name of the machine: {item.machinename}</Text>
                                    <Text>Id of the machine: {item._id}</Text>
                                    <Text>details of the machine: this is a vr machine</Text>
                                </View> */}
        <Card
            containerStyle={{
                shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
                shadowOpacity: 0.1,
                shadowRadius: 20,
                shadowColor: 'black',
                elevation: 8,
                width: '97%'
                // marginLeft: 100
            }}>
            <Card.Title
                style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row'
                }}>
                {item.machinename}
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Divider />
            <Text>Id: {item._id}</Text>

            <Text style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}>Details:</Text>

            <View
                style={{
                    paddingTop: 50,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between'
                }}>
                <Button
                    type='outline'
                    buttonStyle={{
                        width: 100,
                        //backgroundColor: 'darkgrey',
                        // borderColor: 'red',
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        marginRight: 0,
                        marginBottom: 0
                    }}
                    onPress={() => deletealert(item._id, item.machinename)}
                    title='Delete'
                />
                <Button
                    buttonStyle={{
                        width: 150,
                        height: 50,
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        marginLeft: 0,
                        marginRight: 0,
                        marginBottom: 0
                    }}
                    onPress={() => {
                        onPress(item._id, item.machinename);
                    }}
                    title='Add tokens'
                />
            </View>
        </Card>
    </View>
);
```

};

This is the error message im getting after i click on the page that loads this component.

[image]

Comment: where should `initialState` come from in `const [date, setdate] = useState(initialState);`?

Comment: What is initial state in const [ date, setDate] = usestate(initialState) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare `initialState`. Also, I believe it is the default when you use the shortcut to create: `const [date,setDate] = useState(initialState);` you need to initialize by putting a value.

For instance, `const [count,setCount] = useState(0);`